# How to get email from each line and send that line as email to same address, in csh

Tags: shell, file, unix, csh

I have a text file. I need to select the address mail from each line and send each line to the correspond address.

I try to use `foreach` and `awk` to select the address

```
set valuea = `awk '{print $3}' FichierNote`
```

Could you please give me a way how can i do this? This is the data in the file.

```
    8 mariamms maria@gmail.com (cto;MDG_MMS) 
    7 lj16 jean-christophe@gmail.com (gnb;DIG_FMTRD) 
    7 imbse emma.imbspi@gmail.com (gnb;MDG_MMS) 
    6 viviens stephano.vien@gmail.com (gnb;IMD) 
    5 alberghv vinco.alrghina@gmail.com (cto;ADG)
```

Comment: Don't use exact email address in the example. And what do you mean by `send each line to the corresponding address`? Do you want to send `8 user1 user1email@domain.com (cto;MDG_MMS)` line to `user1email@domain.com`?

Comment: @Utsav, yes i want to send  user1 user1email@domain.com (cto;MDG_MMS) to user1email@domain.com

Comment: Thank you @Utsav , your script help me so much

Comment: Please accept the answer which worked for you, so the question could be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a script like below:-

```
    #!/usr/bin/csh

while read -r line
do
  mailId=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3}')
  #echo $mailId
  #here you have to put your mail command
  #example 'sendmail -f source_mail_id.com $mailId < mailContentFile.txt'
done < FichierNote
```

How will the above script work? In `while` loop it will read each line and `awk` command will cut the mail id each time and will store in `mailId` variable. Now you need to put your mail command and put `$mailId` variable as email address.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is an simpler way, but this is what I could think of.

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"|mail -s "your_subject" "$(echo "$line"|awk '{print $3}')"; done < emailList.txt
```

Replace `your_subject` with the main subject.

Assumption: The email is at 3rd column.

Explanation:

1. `while read -r line;do...done < file` will read the file line by line
   and each line will be stored in variable `$line`.
2. `"$(echo"$line"|awk '{print $3}')"` will get the email address to pass to
   `mail` command.
3. `do echo "$line"|mail -s "your_subject" "$(echo "$line"|awk '{print
   $3}')";` will send the line as message body to the email address
   derived in above step.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script I ended up using, with `csh`:

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach line ( "`cat FichierNote`" )
    echo $line | mail -s "Subject" `echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`                      

end
```